# Why Schrodinger equation does not contains internal energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, schroedinger-equation

well i was confused about something when we are comparing Schrodinger equation by classical mechanics,  we can see it contains the total energy (or the Hamiltonian) equals the kinetic energy plus the potential energy $E = \frac{p^2}{2 m} + V$ , now comparing to classical mechanics we can see this relation equals the mechanical energy or the conservation of the mechanical energy, My question are we neglecting the internal energy because it is representing (the kinetic plus the potential) of the Molecules inside a gas for example (this definition of the internal energy is derived from statistical mechanics point of view) and according to schrodinger equation it is representing one electron or one particle and we don't have a molecule, is that a right way of thinking about it?

Comment: In what sense are you differentiating internal energy from the energy inherent to a system? Because in quantum statistical mechanics there is no distinction. The usage of the letter U to refer to internal energy is just bad historical convention.

Comment: @MattHanson , i don't know what is the inherent energy stands for , but my question was not about it , so sorry if i am misunderstanding you

Comment: The “inherent” energy is just the energy. As in all the energy the system has, which is the eignevalue of the Hamiltonian for a stationary state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Internal energy" is a term and concept from thermodynamics, not from classical or quantum mechanics. It is a quantity (real number) characterizing a macroscopic system at rest, whose value can change either via heat or via work, and work is equivalent to heat in this respect. All this constitutes the First Law of thermodynamics.

Internal energy is often visualized as something residing inside the system (in a container). Thus this "internal energy" is not equal to "total energy" which could include contribution due to potential energy of the system in an external field (gravitational, electric), or kinetic energy in case the system is moving as a whole.

Schroedinger's equation is a mathematical theory of microscopic systems, not macroscopic systems, so thermodynamics' concepts such as heat or internal energy are not very relevant to understanding it. The Hamiltonian operator $H$ is related to energy but it is an operator, not a number, thus it is not energy (a number).

Energy of a quantum system may be defined in different ways, but the common point is that in case the psi function is an eigenfunction $\psi_n$ of the Hamiltonian $H$ adopted, energy of the system is that eigenvalue $H_n$ of the Hamiltonian operator which obeys the equation

$$
H\psi_n = H_n\psi_n.
$$

Thus $H$ is used to define energy levels, and energy of the microscopic system. One must choose one definite $H$ out of infinity of different but equivalent operators which could be used to formulate the Schroedinger equation.

It is often customary to describe the microscopic system in the frame where its center is at rest, thus if there is no contribution to energy due to external field, the energy derived off the Hamiltonian is similar to internal energy in thermodynamics, that it is the total energy in the rest frame. But Schroedinger's equation does not require this special frame of reference, and $H$ and $H_n$'s may refer to energy of the system in any frame. So the concept of "internal energy" is not really commonly used and has no special significance in quantum theory of simple microscopic systems such as atom or molecule. Unless one uses quantum theory to formulate a theory underlying/reproducing thermodynamics - then one will of course use the quantum operator counterpart of internal energy, the Hamiltonian of many particle system in the rest frame of the system.

Comment: Lalinsky , i  was looking for this answer , thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

This is the way I would think about it.

Let $\hat{H}$ be the Hamiltonian operator, whose eigenvalues are the allowed energy levels of the system. The formula you stated in your question has $\hat{H} = \frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m} + \hat{V}$. But this is only valid for a single particle, and so to be super explicit we could write $\hat{H} = \frac{\hat{p_1}^2}{2m} + \hat{V}(r_1)$ to make sure that we understand that the operators are acting on the coordinates of one particle.

For an N-particle system the Hamiltonian takes the form:

$\hat{H} = \sum \limits_{i=1}^{N} \left(\frac{\hat{p_i}^2}{2m}\right) + \hat{V}(r_1,r_2,...,r_N,t)$

where t is time.

Hopefully this makes sense: the energy is determined by the sum of all the kinetic energies of each particle, plus a potential term which represents the interactions between the particles. For example, this potential term could be the sum of all the electrostatic interactions between charged particles.

Now we can see that the Hamiltonian in this form doesn't neglect the internal energy: it includes the total KE, plus any energy stored in the interaction between particles. The sum of these two is precisely the internal energy of, for example, a gas.

I hope that helps, and if I have misunderstood your question please let me know.

Sources: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_(quantum_mechanics)

---

Extra Notes:

I agree with Matt Hanson's comment. I think the point is that a definition of "internal energy" is not needed in QM (i.e. there is no point differentiating between the energy of individual particles and the energy of e.g. COM of the system). It is useful in thermodynamics but not here.

Comment: In coupled channel calculation it does. This is referred to as the excitation energy.

Comment: @SAKhan Im confused as to what you are referring to: what is the "it" in your statement?

Comment: @psychgiraffe , Thanks for your answer , i think we are agree about that the internal energy does not included because we are dealing with an individual particels instead of molecules as the gas example what i mean here is according to classical mechanics the total energy should be equals ( kinetic + potential + internal )  , so what i conclude it here is that we can think about the hamiltonian or the total energy as an internal enrgy but not in quantum mechanics , because it should be helpful in statistical and thermodhnamics instead .

Comment: I have replied in the main body of my answer as it wouldnt fit in the comments

Comment: @psychgiraffe , Thanks for your answering again , i think i agree with your answer ...

Comment: Hopefully things make sense, The internal energy is definitely accounted for within the Hamiltonian, there just isnt a reason to distinguish between internal energy and other energy in QM.

Comment: @psychgiraffe it refers to the internal energy. usually intenal energy is vibrational or rotational.

Comment: I definitely don’t agree that thermodynamics is less fundamental. It is actually the only theory of physics that is essentially universal and not even remotely approximate. See Einstein’s lavish praise for the subject. In practical applications we make judicious approximations, but that is not the same as the theory itself being approximate. And it is also completely complementary to quantum mechanics and other theories as well.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, will change it now